# MySQL command line, source to import many files

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to import many `.sql` files using the source command in `mysql` command line interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u have files like

```
1.sql
2.sql
...
n.sql
```

Create a file example.sql include

```
source 1.sql
source 2.sql
....
source n.sql
```

Connect to mysql and source example.sql

```
source example.sql
```

Source multiple files is not possible, but u can include the files to source in a file and source a single file for automating.